# How to set "nth" element of a nested python dict with given list location?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

If I have a dict for example

```
d = { 'a': {
            "x": [],
            "y": {
                "z": {
                    "1": 'loser'
                        }
                 }
            }
    }

print(d['a']['y']['z']['1']) #=> loser
```

However, I don't know how many nested items are in this dict. Instead I have a list of keys like:

```
['a', 'y', 'z', '1']
```

What is an elegant way to set `d['a']['y']['z']['1'] = 'winner'`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
l = ['a', 'y', 'z', '1']

def change_the_value(d, l, value):
    if len(l) == 1:
        d[l[0]] = value
    if len(l) == 2:
        d[l[0]][l[1]] = value
    if len(l) == 3:
        d[l[0]][l[1]][l[2]] = value
    if len(l) == 4:
        d[l[0]][l[1]][l[2]][l[3]] = value
    # ... ad infinitum
    return d

change_the_value(d, l, 'winner')
print(d) # => {'a': {'x': [], 'y': {'z': {'1': 'winner'}}}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
_path = ['a', 'y', 'z', '1']
d = {'a': {'x': [], 'y': {'z': {'1': 'loser'}}}}
_start = d
for i in _path[:-1]:
   _start = _start[i]

_start[_path[-1]] = 'winner'
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'x': [], 'y': {'z': {'1': 'winner'}}}}
```

You can also use recursion (if you do not mind creating a new structure for `d`):

```
def update(_d, _path):
  return {a:'winner' if a == _path[-1] and len(_path) == 1 else 
    update(b, _path[1:]) if a == _path[0] else b for a, b in _d.items()}

print(update(d, ['a', 'y', 'z', '1']))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'x': [], 'y': {'z': {'1': 'winner'}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I started out with something like this but couldn't quite finish it because I didn't grok how the dictionary's copy was modifying the same memory space.

Comment: @Conner There is actually a reference to `d` from `_start`. Thus, any mutations of `_start` will also appear in `d`.

Answer (score 6):

If you can be sure that the list of keys is valid, you can use `functools.reduce`.

```
>>> from functools import reduce 
>>>
>>> keys = ['a', 'y', 'z', '1']                                                                                     
>>> d = { 'a': { 
...:             "x": [], 
...:             "y": { 
...:                 "z": { 
...:                     "1": 'loser' 
...:                         } 
...:                  } 
...:             } 
...:     }                                                                                                             
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> the_dict = reduce(dict.get, keys[:-1], d)                                                                          
>>> the_dict[keys[-1]] = 'winner'                                                                                      
>>> d                                                                                                                  
{'a': {'x': [], 'y': {'z': {'1': 'winner'}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it, for any length of `l`!

```
tmp = d
for key in l[:-1]:
    tmp = tmp[key]

tmp[l[-1]] = 'winner'
```

I have a feeling there must be a better way, but this at least eliminates all those `if` statements.

Comment: No, that's perfectly fine. +1

Comment: I do like @timgeb's `reduce` version a bit better because, hey, it's a one-liner! It might be faster too, depending on how `reduce` implements its internal loop compared to my Python-level `for` loop. I like mine for being more immediately obvious since, even though I use `functools` regularly, I had to look up the signature of `reduce`. Both clearly have merits!

Answer (score 0):

There are other good answers posted if you have a list of keys. I noticed that your example is looking for the first string value. If that's always true, here's a solution that will work without a list of keys:

```
def setval(d, val):
  for i in d:
    if isinstance(d[i], dict):
      return setval(d[i], val)
    if isinstance(d[i], str):
      d[i] = val
      return
  return None

setval(d, 'winner')
print(d)
```

Alternatively, if you do want to use a list to specify the path, here's a recursive approach:

```
def setvalat(d, l, val):
  if len(l) > 1:
    setvalat(d[l[0]], l[1:], val)
  else:
    d[l[0]] = val

setvalat(d, ['a', 'y', 'z', '1'], 'winner')
print(d)
```